# node.js body on http request object vs body on express request object

Tags: node.js, sockets, http, express

I'm trying to build an http module that suppose to work with an express server.

while reading the http module api, I see that it doesn't save the body inside the request object. 
So my questions are:

1. If I want to build an express server which works with the official http module, how should I get the body?
2. I consider to implement the `http module` in the following way: listening to the socket, and if I get `content-length` header, listetning to the rest of the socket stream till I get all the body, save it as a memeber of the http request, and only then send the request object to the express server handler.

What are the pros and cons of my suggestion above vs letting the express server to "listen" to the body of the request via request.on('data',callback(data))

I mean , why shouldn't I keep the body inside the 'request' object the same way I keep the headers?

Comment: Body of the request - do you mean POST data ?

Comment: yes, for example. yes

Comment: To get the body data, you have to parse the request body yourself. Your approach is reasonable, but why don't you just use the parser provided by express? What is stopping you from doing that?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It's hard to answer your question without knowing exactly what you want to do.  But I can give you some detail about how the request body is handled by Node/Express, and hopefully you can take things from there.

When handling a request (either directly via Node's request handler, or through Express's request handlers), the body of the request won't automatically be received: you have to open an HTTP stream to receive it.

The type of the body content should be determined by the `Content-Type` request header.  The two most common body types are `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` and `multipart/form-data`.  It's possible, however, to use any content type you want, which is usually more common for APIs (for example, using `application/json` is becoming more common for REST APIs).

`application/x-www-form-urlencoded` is pretty straightforward; `name=value` pairs are URL encoded (using JavaScript's built-in `encodeURIComponent`, for example), then combined with an ampersand (&).  They're usually UTF-8 encoded, but that can also be specified in `Content-Type`.

`multipart/form-data` is more complicated, and can also typically be quite large, as vkurchatkin's answer points out (meaning you may not want to bring it into memory).

Express makes available some middleware to automatically handle the various types of body parsing.  Usually, people simply use `bodyParser`, though you have to be careful with that middleware.  It's really just a convenience middleware that combines `json`, `urlencoded`, and `multipart`.  However, `multipart` has been deprecated.  Express is still bundling Connect 2.12, which still includes `multipart`.  When Express updates its dependency, though, the situation will change.

As I write this, `bodyParser`, `json`, `urlencoded`, and `multipart` have all been removed from Connect.  Everything but `multipart` has been moved into the module `body-parser` (https://github.com/expressjs/body-parser).  If you need multipart support, I recommend Busboy (https://npmjs.org/package/busboy), which is very robust.  At some point, Express will update it's dependency on Connect, and will most likely add a dependency to `body-parser` since it has been removed from Connect.

So, since `bodyParser` bundles deprecated code (`multipart`), I recommend explicitly linking in only `json` and `urlencoded` (and you could even omit `json` if you're not accepting any JSON-encoded bodies):

```
app.use(express.json());
app.use(express.urlencoded());
```

If you're writing middleware, you probably don't want to automatically link in `json` and `urlencoded` (much less Busboy); that would break the modular nature of Express.  However, you should specify in your documentation that your middleware requires the `req.body` object to be available (and fail gracefully if it isn't): you can go on to say that `json`, `urlencoded`, and Busboy all provide the `req.body` object, depending on what kind of content types you need to accept.

If you dig into the source code for `urlencoded` or `json`, you will find that they rely on another Node module, `raw-body`, which simply opens the request stream and retrieves the body content.  If you really need to know the details of retrieving the body from a request, you will find everything you need in the source code for that module (https://github.com/stream-utils/raw-body/blob/master/index.js).

I know that's a lot of detail, but they're important details!

Answer (score 0):

You can do that, it fairly simple. `bodyParser` middleware does that, for example (https://github.com/expressjs/body-parser/blob/master/index.js#L27). The thing is, request body can be really large (file upload, for example), so you generally don't want to put that in memory. Rather you can stream it to disk or s3 or whatnot.