# Changing form type to multipart/form-data causes req.body to be empty

Tags: json, forms, node.js, express

When I set up my form without specifying an `enctype`, Firefox automatically sets it to `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` and `req.body` contains a nice, JSON representation of all the parameters entered into the form. But when I change the enctype to `multipart/form-data` `req.body` is suddenly empty.

This is my form:

```
<form action="/create" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
  <fieldset>
    <div>
      <label>Category:</label>
    </div>
    <div>
      <select name="category">
      <option value="standard">Standard</option>
      <option value="custom">Custom</option>
    </div>
    <div>
      <input type="text" name="description">
    </div>
    <div>
      <label>User ID:</label>
    </div>
    <div>
      <input type="text" name="userid">
    </div>
    <div>
      <input type="submit" value="Go">
    </div>
  </fieldset>
</form>
```

Doing a `console.log(JSON.stringify(req.body, null, 2));` prints out an empty object when `enctype` is `multipart/form-data` and when `enctype` is not specified, it prints out something like:

```
{
  category: "standard",
  userid: "foo"
}
```

Any reason this is happening?

Answer (score 2):

Try use busboy-body-parser to retrieve the request body parameters and the files.

```
start.js
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var busboyBodyParser = require('busboy-body-parser');


// parse application/x-www-form-urlencoded
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({
  extended: true
}));

// parse application/json
app.use(bodyParser.json());


//parse multipart/form-data    
app.use(busboyBodyParser());



controllers/someController.js
someAction: function(req,res){
     if(req.method == "POST"){
           res.end(JSON.stringify(req.body)+JSON.stringify(req.files));
     }
}
//{"text":"testx"}{"anexo":{"data":{"type":"Buffer","data":.... }}} 
//req.body = {"text":"testx"}
//req.files = {"anexo":{"data":{"type":"Buffer","data":.... }}} 


views/someController/someAction.html
<form method="post" id="multipart" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <input type="text" id="text1" name="text" value="testx" />
    <input type="file" id="anexo" name="anexo"  />
    <input type="submit" value="Enviar" />
</form>
```

To create a file uploaded, you need work if the stream, for example:

```
/* file props
{  
   "data":{"type":"Buffer","data":.... },
   "fieldname":"anexo",
   "originalname":"images (1).jpg",
   "encoding":"7bit",
   "mimetype":"image/jpeg",
   "destination":"c:\\live\\sources\\uploads\\",
   "filename":"eventclock_images (1)_1443706175833.jpg",
   "path":"c:\\live\\sources\\uploads\\eventclock_images(1)_1443706175833.jpg",
   "size":9986
}
*/

var fileStream = fs.createWriteStream(file.path);
fileStream.write(file.data);
fileStream.end();

fileStream.on('error', function (err) {
    //console.log("error",err);
});
fileStream.on('finish', function (res) {
    //console.log("finish",res);
});
```

Comment: You should not answer with your case. Consider the case of the questioner.

Comment: @Anderson, By using busboy-body-parser, I am still getting an empty request body.

Comment: @Jayna Tanawala I guess, that today you can find a better parser to solve this kind of situation. Maybe the multer parser, give a look here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60092649/how-to-get-request-body-in-node-js-middle-ware-from-multi-part-form-data

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like you're using `express.urlencoded()` instead of `express.multipart()`.

Comment: Thanks. I'm new to Express and was just using the standard set up. Didn't realize that was something that needed to be changed in app.js

Comment: @robertklep, you're probably correct (impossible to tell for sure without seeing the OPs Express code), but `express.multipart` (really a Connect middleware) is deprecated and should not be used.  See my answer for alternatives.

Comment: @EthanBrown I don't entirely disagree with you, but IMO, if something is deprecated it should be removed. As long as it's still available, I'll use it. Similarly with [unstable notices](http://nodejs.org/api/stream.html#stream_stream), by the way.

Comment: I mostly agree with you on that point, Robert: I wish Express would remove it.  But then I've never had to maintain backwards compatibility for a framework that gets downloaded half a million times a month!  In this _particular_ case, using `bodyParser` is exactly equivalent to using `json`, `urlencoded`, and `multipart`, in that order.  To me it's actually clearer to use these middlewares separately.  And since Busboy is more robust than `multipart` (and it has a future), well, it seems obstinate not to use it.

Answer (score 1):

I think @robertklep is correct, but I disagree with his answer.  `express.multipart()` is [deprecated and should not be used](http://www.senchalabs.org/connect/multipart.html).

If you need multipart form processing, I highly recommend [Busboy](https://npmjs.org/package/busboy).  If you want all the details, see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20978724/node-js-body-on-http-request-object-vs-body-on-express-request-object/20984555#20984555).

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19581146/how-to-get-rid-of-connect-3-0-deprecation-alert - you can work around the deprecation notice, which will be fixed when Express uses Connect 3.0.

Comment: That answer is exactly what I'm recommending the poster do.  If you read the answer I referenced, it includes all the details.  But yes: to avoid the deprecation notice, use `json` and `urlencoded` explicitly instead of using `bodyParser` is the upshot.  Specifically, though, I am saying *don't* use `multipart`, which is deprecated, and gets to the heart of the OP's answer.

Comment: OH! So you did didn't see that. Good stuff.

Comment: Eh, I could have been more explicit about it.  Thanks for clarifying!

Answer (score -1):

```
npm install multer --save

in main.js

var multer  =   require('multer');
var upload = multer()

router.route("/quotes").post(upload.array(),function(req, res, next){
        name = req.body.name;
        email = req.body.email;
}
```

Comment: It's always a good idea to include some explanation what you code does.